# UIButton (checkbox) in custom UITableView subclass - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I asked a version of this question before but I failed to mention my `UIButton` checkboxes were in a `UITableVlewCell`. I was told to subclass this from a `UITableViewCell` instead of a `UIButton`. It's a to-do list app so I'm making this in a prototype cell. Currently, I'm able to run the app but not save the state of the checkbox using `NSUserDefaults`. I've followed a tutorial from YouTube and even downloaded the files along with it and converted them from Objective-C to Swift. When I tried to put all the code in the View Controller without a subclass, I got the error message `"..Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."` In the subclass, I'm able to run the app but nothing saves. I'm also unsure of what else to call in my `viewDidLoad()` method.

My code is as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // NSUserDefaults

    checked = defaults.boolForKey("boxIsChecked")

}
```

My subclass:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let isSelected = UIImage(named: "Selected")
let unselected = UIImage(named: "Unselected")


@IBOutlet weak var checkBoxButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func checkBox(sender: UIButton) {
    if (!checked) {
        checked = true
        checkBoxButton.setImage(isSelected, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        defaults.setBool(checked, forKey: "boxIsChecked")
    }

    else if (checked) {
        checked = false
        checkBoxButton.setImage(unselected, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        defaults.setBool(checked, forKey: "boxIsChecked")
    }

}

func checkTheBox() {
    if (!checked) {
        checkBoxButton.setImage(unselected, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    else if (checked) {
        checkBoxButton.setImage(isSelected, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


}
```

NOTE: `var checked: Bool = true` is a global variable in my first View Controller. I'm unsure if I need to initialize this as `var checked: Bool`. I have tried and got many error messages. Thank you for your help.

ALSO:: When I add `TableViewCell().checkTheBox()` to the `viewDidLoad()` method, I get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` on the statement under `else if` in the `checkTheBox` method.

Comment: What is the outlet connected to?

Comment: @PietroRea right now the IBOutlet "checkBoxButton" is connected to the UIButton in the Prototype UITableViewCell.

Comment: @PietroRea and it's also connected to the subclass "TableViewCell"